# How to install Logstash for NodeJs on Windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, logstash

I want to install Logstash for NodeJs on windows 7, but I am not able to find proper steps for the same.
Can any one please help!

Comment: Logstash is not a plugin for Node.js. Logstash is a standalone application that represents a pipeline with an input and potentially many outputs.

Comment: I want to know how to install and make it work with NodeJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, logstash has nothing to do with nodejs.

What you're looking to do is install Logstash on Windows, something that you can find out about by using google, there will be loads of guides out there describing how to do this.

You would then need to configure logstash to look in the right location for the log files it needs to process, and then set up filters to handle nodejs style logs (which as far as I understand aren't very well standardised). You then need to configure an output (logstash is essentially a unix pipe on steroids and needs somewhere to save the logs it has processed). Elasticsearch is the most common thing to save logs to.

Personally, in my environment, I would install logstash on a CentOS server, as it's a well established process, and ship the logs from your Windows 7 machine to the logstash server using either logstash forwarder or nxlog. That way you can have logs coming in from a number of different sources and you can still reboot your Windows machine every few days as required by Windows update without your logstash server going down.

Answer (score 2):

There is the option of [node-logstash](https://github.com/bpaquet/node-logstash) if you want a node.js alternative to Logstash.  This isn't something I'm using myself (I'm using nxlog in Windows instead) but it looks like a decent alternative to the standard JRuby Logstash if you need to forward logs from Windows.

Instructions from the [readme](https://github.com/bpaquet/node-logstash#installation) are below:

### Installation

- Install NodeJS, version >= 0.10, or [io.js](https://iojs.org).
- Install build tools

  - Debian based system: `apt-get install build-essential`
  - Centos system: `yum install gcc gcc-c++ make`
- Install zmq dev libraries: This is required to build the [node zeromq module](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node).

  - Debian based system: `apt-get install libzmq1`. Under recent releases, this package is present in default repositories. On ubuntu lucid, use this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/zeromq). On debian squeeze, use [backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/).
  - Centos 6: `yum install zeromq zeromq-devel`. Before, you have to add the rpm zeromq repo : `curl http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/fengshuo:/zeromq/CentOS_CentOS-6/home:fengshuo:zeromq.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/zeromq.repo`
- Clone repository: `git clone git://github.com/bpaquet/node-logstash.git && cd node-logstash`
- Install dependencies: `npm install`.

The executable is in `bin/node-logstash-agent`

You have scripts in `dists` folder to build packages. Actually, only debian is supported.